# Desktop Organization

Tags: windows-10, desktop-computer

Is it possible to outline or "box-in" similar shortcut icons on the desktop to help organize similar shortcuts? For example; gather all my travel icon/shortcuts into one "box."

Comment: You could draw your own background with boxes on it, but I suspect that isn't exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new folder by right clicking on the desktop, then clicking “New Folder”. Type a name for the folder then drag all the desktop icons into that folder.

See [this article](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-create-folder-on-desktop/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

There are some third-party products for that.

The most well-known is
[Stardock Fences](https://www.stardock.com/products/fences/).
Unfortunately it's payware at €11.99.

[image]

You see some free alternatives to Stardock Fences on
[link](https://alternativeto.net/software/fences/?license=free&platform=windows).